# Touchscreen application for Raspberry3B

Tags: touchscreen, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am looking to create a touchscreen application on Raspberry 3B or Raspberry 3B+. My concern is can we create it using PyQt5 and using buster as OS, and how can we use on screen keyboard just like android? Please help, I am new in the raspberry world

Comment: The Pi is a general Linux box.  Search for a general Linux solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.